# How send large video file to server with chunking in android

Tags: android, kotlin, video, ktor, ktor-client

I want to send a large video to the server but I have to split the video into multiple parts and send each of the parts to be sent consecutively. Which approach I must use?
Note: I use ktor client to connect to the server

Comment: The best approach would be to split the file in multiple parts and send those consecutively.

Comment: @blackapps Do you have any kotlin sample code?

Comment: Do you want to make an HTTP request for each part or send parts in one request?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I want an HTTP request for each part, The chunks are sent in sequential order, and the next chunk can be sent to the server according to the success of the previous chunk.

Comment: You can send a request body as a `ByteArray` of a video part https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#body and a header indicating what video is being uploaded.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman could you please write a sample code here?

Comment: It would be better if you try to make some solution and then ask specific questions about problems that you have.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman you are right, but I don't have any idea to do that

Comment: Then start by reading the documentation and trying to send simple POST requests with a binary body and receiving them on a server.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I know about POST requests in ktor but i don't know about how can i split video file to multiple parts

Comment: Here is an idea of how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575658/13963150